# Custom TextView in ToolBar getting Clipped

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-toolbar

I am using a custom toolbar layout with a EditText placed for searching. The textbox is getting clipped on the top. Please see the attached screen shot,

[image]

Here is the layout file for the toolbar.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/appColor"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Toolbar Title"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="10pt"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_MapFlip"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:tag="0"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/post_job_slide"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_Background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_field">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/searchBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:hint="@string/search_hint"
            android:inputType="text">
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Why is the text getting clipped on top? Is this the proper way to add EditText in toolbar?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe 30dp layout_height @+id/layout_Background is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the height of Relative Layout from 30 dp to wrap_content. Because of 30 dp height of Relative layout which is the parent of your edit text, your edit text height will also become 30dp.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_Background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/search_field">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/searchBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:hint="@string/search_hint"
            android:inputType="text">
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
        </RelativeLayout>
```